# Searchfilter only works on GetCollection, I want it on Get

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, api-platform.com

I have the following annotation written in my Entity `RegistrationHashes` in API platform:

```
#[ORM\Entity()]
#[ORM\Table(name: "registration_hashes")]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [new Get(), new GetCollection()],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
    security: 'is_granted("ROLE_USER")',
)]
#[ApiFilter(
    filterClass: SearchFilter::class,
    properties: [
        'registrationId' => SearchFilterInterface::STRATEGY_START,
        'hash' => SearchFilterInterface::STRATEGY_EXACT,
    ]
)]
```

When query `/registration_hashes` I can search for the two properties `registrationId` and `hash` They match and this works.  Except I dont want to return a collection, I just want either the one row or not found.  How can I apply my SearchFilter to GET operation only?

Answer (score 1):

`Get` operation is not made to do that and can't be use like you want to.
`Get` operation always need an api identifier in order to retrieve an item based on it. `registrationId` in your case.

If you want to search for items you will always need to use collection operations.
In your case, just call your `getCollection` operation with the needed parameters.
Something like that :

```
/api/registration_hashes?registrationId=xxx&hash=xxx
```

If you combination of registration and hash is unique you will get only one result.

Also, Search Filter of api platform are made to work only on collection operations. Its intentional.

---

Update :

One way to do it is to do something like that :

```
new Get(
   uriTemplate: "/users/{registrationId}/{hash}
   provider: CustomProvider::class
)
```

And do your own logic inside `CustomProvider.php` to get the object using

```
public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = [])
{
    $hash = $uriVariables['hash'];
    $registrationId = $uriVariables['registrationId']


   //You own logic to get it from database
}
```

Look at https://api-platform.com/docs/main/core/state-providers/ for deeper explanation about state provider

Comment: But what If I only want to return one row? GetCollection returns a lot of data around the collection itself.   I literally just want the one JSON array back (just like the GET returns).  Is that not possible? And what are the reasons behind that?